# In which countries are McDonald's fries vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, restaurant

I've heard mixed information about whether McDonald's fries are vegan, and then I've heard that it can vary based on which country you're in. So is there a short list of countries where McDonald's fries are vegan?

Comment: It might be a shorter list to say where they _aren't_ vegan, depending on what the standard recipe is; I'm assuming you'll accept whichever "direction" makes a shorter list :)

Comment: @Erica yes of course!

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question as too broad. As Vaelus says, such a list would quickly become inaccurate. Asking about a specific country would be more appropriate in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Any list of countries to answer this question has the potential to suddenly become incorrect if any Country's McDonald's change their recipe, so I don't think it's a good idea to compile a list here. Instead, you should ask your server, or find the information on the relevant regional McDonald's website.

For reference, here are links various countries McDonald's statements about fries:

- [U.S.A](https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/product/small-french-fries.html#ingredients)
- [Japan](http://www.mcdonalds.co.jp/quality/basic_information/menu_info.php?mid=6351#)
- [China](https://www.mcdonalds.com.cn/product/French-Fries) (I think)
- [Germany](https://www.mcdonalds.de/qualitaet/export/sites/default/media/dokumente/Zutaten_Inhaltsstoffe_Standardprodukte_McDonalds.pdf#page=20)
- [Canada](https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/about-our-food/making-informed-choices/vegetarian-vegan-options.html)
- [France](https://www.mcdonalds.fr/produits/sauces/frites#)
- [United Kingdom](https://www.mcdonalds.com/gb/en-gb/product/fries-medium.html#ingredients)
- [Australia](https://mcdonalds.com.au/sites/mcdonalds.com.au/files/Main%20Food%20Menu%20-%20Allergen%2C%20Ingredients%20and%20Nutrition%20Information_0.pdf#page=11)

These are the 8 countries with the most McDonalds locations as listed [here](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/countries-with-the-most-mcdonald-s-restaurant.html)