# Are McDonald's fries vegan in Canada?

Tags: is-it-vegan, restaurant, canada

I've heard mixed information about whether McDonald's fries are vegan. There's mixed information about flavourings used in manufacture, or different fats used for deep frying. Even this recent [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vegetarian/comments/c2jk0t/mcdonalds_fries_arent_vegetarianfriendly/) seems to have mixed information. And since it [varies by country](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/in-which-countries-are-mcdonalds-fries-vegan), I'll ask this question in the context of Canada specifically.

Are McDonald's fries vegan in Canada?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. According to [their official website for Canada](https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/about-our-food/making-informed-choices/vegetarian-vegan-options.html) (emphasis mine):

> Fries and Hash Browns
>
> **Our World Famous Fries™ and hash browns are go-tos for our vegetarian
> and vegan guests**. Since 2007, we’ve made them without any
> animal-sourced ingredients. We cook them in 100% vegetable oil, in a
> dedicated fryer separate from our meat items.

Additionally, from their nutrition calculator you can get a full list of the ingredients in their fries:

> **French Fries:**
> Potatoes, canola oil, hydrogenated soybean oil, safflower oil, natural
> flavour (vegetable source), dextrose, sodium acid pyrophosphate
> (maintain colour), citric acid (preservative), dimethylpolysiloxane
> (anti-foaming agent), cooked in vegetable oil (canola oil, corn oil,
> soybean oil, hydrogenated soybean oil, citric acid,
> dimethylpolysiloxane)
>
> **Salt**:
> Salt, silicoaluminate, dextrose, potassium iodide